# How can I show geolocation of one specific photo on a map in iOS?

Tags: ios, photos, geolocation

Just changed from Samsung Galaxy 5 to iPhone. Galaxy's feature I liked was click on a photo, then more info, and if the photo was geotagged, it would open a map showing location.

I can only show location of groups of photos on my iPhone, is there any way to select a single photo and show the location on a map? I see the generic location (i.e., Downtown Long Beach) but I can not see a specific location.

Anyone know a way to bring up a map of a single selected photo?

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 12 *fsb’s* answer doesn’t seem to work any more. A different way is via Apple’s *Shortcut* app. In the gallery you can find a shortcut named “Where was this taken?”. If you add this and let the actions show up in the share sheet. Then you will be taken to the location by:

1. Select the photo
2. Press the “share” icon
3. Select “Shortcuts”
4. Select “Where was this taken?”
5. Done, you should now see the map app and the location of your photo

Answer (score 1):

You can see the exact location by following these steps (iOS 9.3.1).  These steps assume the photo contains geolocation info, this info might have been removed by the author.

1. In `Settings`, ensure you can see locations for photos in `Privacy --> Location Services --> Camera`.
2. In `Photos`, find the image, or images, you want the location.  There will be a header across the top with the general location.
3. Tap on the general location header (i.e. Downtown Long Beach), **not** the image.  This will take you to the Maps app with the location the image was taken.  If there's multiple images, you can see the exact location for each image.

Comment: Does not seem to work anymore on iOS 13.

Answer (score 1):

For years I've downloaded iPhone photos to a Windows PC and opened them in Irfanview (an amazing free photo handling tool.) With a photo open you select Image>Information>EXIF info*>Show in Google Maps (or Google Earth, or Open Street, or Geo-Hack Wiki) and the map with ~ location shows up. The accuracy can be +/- 3-5 feet.